# Autosar based Secoc

Tags: security, capl, canoe, autosar, cmac

I have to create one scenario in CAPL. In Canoe Cybersecurity Secoc, needs to send one secured I-pdu from one ecu to another ecu. we using data and Time based Freshness to calculate
CMAC. Is that possible to gnerate the CMAC and send to another ECU. if it is possible also , how we are sending and recieving this data . could anyone please help me on this ?

I have tried with one function in CAPL SecurityLocalGenerateCMAC(keyData, keyLength, data, dataLength, cmac, cmacLength). but with this function we can generate the CMAC but at the recieving side I don't know hpw to validate this CAMC (means with which function ,I can validate)

Comment: AFAIK, the ISecuredIPdu is transmitted with the payload data and freshness value and CMAC to the receiver(s), which calculated also the CMAC from the received payload and freshness value, and compare the CMAC against the received one.